# Pandas aggregate -- how to retain all columns

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

Example dataframe:

```
rand = np.random.RandomState(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['group1', 'group2', 'group3'] * 2,
                'B': rand.rand(6),
                'C': rand.rand(6),
                'D': rand.rand(6)})
```

print df

```
        A         B         C         D
0  group1  0.417022  0.186260  0.204452
1  group2  0.720324  0.345561  0.878117
2  group3  0.000114  0.396767  0.027388
3  group1  0.302333  0.538817  0.670468
4  group2  0.146756  0.419195  0.417305
5  group3  0.092339  0.685220  0.558690
```

Groupby column A

```
group = df.groupby('A')
```

Use agg to return max value for each group

```
max1 = group['B'].agg({'max' : np.max})
print max1

             max
A               
group1  0.417022
group2  0.720324
group3  0.092339
```

But I would like to retain (or get back) the appropriate data in the other columns, C and D. This would be the remaining data for the row which contained the max value.
So, the return should be:

```
     A         B         C         D
group1  0.417022  0.186260  0.204452
group2  0.720324  0.345561  0.878117
group3  0.092339  0.685220  0.558690
```

Can anybody show how to do this? Any help appreciated.

Comment: I've edited your prior questions to remove your signature. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior): *Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page.* No need to sign-off with your name at the end of a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two stages: first find indices, then lookup all the rows.

```
idx = df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x['B'].argmax())
idx

Out[362]: 
A
group1    0
group2    1
group3    5

df.loc[idx]

Out[364]: 
        A         B         C         D
0  group1  0.417022  0.186260  0.204452
1  group2  0.720324  0.345561  0.878117
5  group3  0.092339  0.685220  0.558690
```

Comment: Is there an option to get the rows with the second maximum value in B?

Comment: This won't work anymore. I don't know when it did but now idx would be [0, 0, 1] and not [0, 1, 5] as suggested in this answer.

Answer (score 4):

My answer is similar to FooBar but is done in one line by using idmax()

```
df.loc[df.groupby('A')['B'].idxmax()]
```

Result is the same:

```
In [51]: df
Out[51]: 
        A         B         C         D
0  group1  0.417022  0.186260  0.204452
1  group2  0.720324  0.345561  0.878117
2  group3  0.000114  0.396767  0.027388
3  group1  0.302333  0.538817  0.670468
4  group2  0.146756  0.419195  0.417305
5  group3  0.092339  0.685220  0.558690

In [76]: df.loc[df.groupby('A')['B'].idxmax()]
Out[76]: 
        A         B         C         D
0  group1  0.417022  0.186260  0.204452
1  group2  0.720324  0.345561  0.878117
5  group3  0.092339  0.685220  0.558690
```

Comment: The nice thing about Python is that you can almost always collaps your code into one line. I chose not to for the educational factor.

Comment: Thankyou, guys. You can be sure I appreciate the information and the education...