# Pandas groupby Aggregation, how to choose output columns.

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have data for which as in the example below Sub is unique but Que is not. Cov is a relation between Sub and Que. In the case where there are multiple Que matched with the same Sub I want to choose the Que with the max Cov.

Ss an example S2 is match with 3 Que:

```
dt = DataFrame([['s1', 'q1', 1], ['s2', 'q2', 1.5], ['s2', 'q3', 2.3], ['s2', 'q4', 2], ['s3', 'q5', 4]], columns = ['Sub', 'Que', 'Cov'])
dup_counts = dt.groupby(["Sub" ,"Que"]).Que.count().groupby(level='Sub').count()
print(dup_counts.head())

Sub
s1     1
s2     3
s3     1
dtype: int64
```

The following code does almost what I want, It returns the max Cov for each Sub. I want to also know the Que associated with that Cov.

```
dup_max = dt.groupby(["Sub","Que"]).Cov.max().groupby(level="Sub").max()
print(dup_max.head())

Sub
s1     1.0
s2     2.3
s3     4.0
dtype: float64
```

This is what I would like to get.

```
Sub    Que   Cov
s1     q1    1.0
s2     q3    2.3
s3     q5    4.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See also [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385374/pandas-aggregate-how-to-retain-all-columns).

```
idx = dt.groupby('Sub').Cov.idxmax()
dt.iloc[idx]
Out[483]: 
  Sub Que  Cov
0  s1  q1  1.0
2  s2  q3  2.3
4  s3  q5  4.0
```